# How does jQuery .load() work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Someone, ( @Denis ) helped me figure out this much, but I do not quite understand what load() really achieves or why the reference to "**some_html**" is done.

I think that Denis meant this to be the python code to load the site originally, as I understand it.

```
def some_html():
    return render('my_template.tpl')
```

And this is the script which calls back python to get more data and it baffles me somewhat.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#result_from_server').load('/some_html');
</script>
```

What I can't seem to understand is why the reference to the original Python method **"/some_html"** ?  I would expect a reference to a **new method** in python, one which specializes in replying to that call from javascript.

The DIV with id=" **result_from_server** " I guess will act as a pseudo variable or container in HTML to receive the result.  That is fairly clear, I think.

```
<div id="result_from_server"></div>
```

If anyone can help me understand how this request works I would appreciate it.  I do understand that different types of data can be passed back from python.  But I see no typing of any kind.  I assume that means that this snippet is for passing text, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'/some_html'` does not reference a Python method.  It is as ignorant of Python as I am!  In this case, it is the URL for the jQuery's ajax call (the `load` method).  I assume that your Python code's end result is mapping a code template to a URL.

Comment: Yes, but **I do not want** to leave that site and reload another one on top of it or navigate away from it to handle the result.  I want to just fetch the data without a blink and make the new data appear where it belongs.

Comment: What you just said is basically what AJAX is.  It happens on the client side.  A new page is never loaded.  The currently loaded page goes out and talks to the "/some_html" url, gets a response back and stuffs it into the div of the page that has already been loaded.

Comment: I see.  This is not calling back Python to get the job done!  So, where is the code which is supposed to fetch the data encoded?  Is it another JavaScript function in the same /some_html URL?  If so, then which one?  It appears to me that more direction needs to be passed along to instruct on how to get the data.. @Danimal37

Comment: When you hit a URL, you simply get a chunk of text back.  It could be HTML, JSON, XML.  Simple experiment: what happens when you type "yourwebsitehere.com/some_html" into your web browser?

Comment: I see, @Danimal37 the information returned is HTML code to expand the site HTML!

Comment: But how would Ajax know which portion to add to the site @Danimal37!

Comment: I think that I get it.  This is not what I need!  I need to get data like strings, numbers, lists, dictionaries etc...  I'm barking up the wrong tree!  So sorry.  I'm new to this... very new...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps missing the "$" for jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#result_from_server').load('/some_html');
</script>
```

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

from:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: That sounds great and believe it or not, I get most of that, being new to jQuery.  What I do not get is why refer back to **some_html** .  I would want to call some independent method in python, like " **fetch_all_client_ids** " specially designed to fetch the data needed.  Why call the original method which loaded the html site on the client?  Can you help me with figuring that out?  I have no code to handle this request in **some_html**  TIA

Comment: It seems clear that I do not really understand the nature of " **.load()** " @SSH This and I have read all about ajax() $.get() and .load() .  Something is missing in my understanding of this.

Comment: @Dennis Kean - You are correct in thinking that the URL for the AJAX call should be specially designed for returning data.  If the URL passed to the AJAX method is the same one that loaded the HTML of the current document, then that does not make sense to me either.

Comment: Wait a minute, @Danimal37.  So, how would I encode instructions whereby Ajax can figure out how to fetch the additional data?  And in what language is that done, AJAX?